# How can I evaluate a list of strings as a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, string, tuples, abstract-syntax-tree, literals

I have a list of thousands of elements of a form like the following:

```
pixels = ['(112, 37, 137, 255)', '(129, 39, 145, 255)', '(125, 036, 138, 255)' ...]
```

I am trying to convert these string elements to tuples using `ast.literal_eval`, but it is breaking on encountering things like leading zeros (e.g. in the third tuple string shown) with the error `SyntaxError: invalid token`.

```
pixels = [ast.literal_eval(pixel) for pixel in pixels]
```

What would be a good way to deal with things like this and get this list of strings evaluated as a list of tuples?

Comment: @BhargavRao Octal numbers in Python 3 don't support the 0xx format.

Comment: @BhargavRao Hi there. The specific error is ```SyntaxError: invalid token```. I've just added that to the question.

Comment: @BhargavRao A leading `0` in Python 2.x was an octal literal. In Python 3.x this is no longer allowed. For example `055` is octal for the decimal value `45`.

Comment: I was waiting for the OP to clarify if he is using 2.x or 3.x (coz it becomes octal in 2x). Thanks.

Comment: Btw, you might need to hunt down whatever generated this, to figure out why it outputs `37` and `39` but `036`, and whether the difference signifies anything.

Comment: @SteveJessop Hehe, a machine learning algorithm generated this. It made a good effort. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re` module.

```
>>> import re
>>> import ast
>>> pixels = ['(112, 37, 137, 255)', '(129, 39, 145, 255)', '(125, 036, 138, 255)']
>>> [ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'\b0+', '', pixel)) for pixel in pixels]
[(112, 37, 137, 255), (129, 39, 145, 255), (125, 36, 138, 255)]
```

`re.sub(r'\b0+', '', pixel)` helps to remove the leading zeros. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character or vice-versa, so here there must be an word boundary exists before  zero and after the space or `(` symbol.

**Update:**

```
>>> pixels = ['(0, 0, 0, 255)', '(129, 39, 145, 255)', '(125, 036, 138, 255)']
>>> [ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'\b0+\B', '', pixel)) for pixel in pixels]
[(0, 0, 0, 255), (129, 39, 145, 255), (125, 36, 138, 255)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this. Your solution is very close, but it is breaking zero elements of tuples, for example, ```(0, 0, 0, 255)``` gets evaluated to ```(, , , 255)```. Would you happen to know a way around this?

Comment: Goood catch, try `[ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'\b0+\B', '', pixel)) for pixel in pixels]`

Comment: An alternate regex approach: `[tuple(int(d) for d in re.findall('\d+', pixel)) for pixel in pixels]`.  (Not as good as posted answer.)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hey, thank you very much for your help on that and for your clear explanations. :)

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `ast.literal_eval` or `re`. Just strip the parentheses and coerce to integers:

```
def tupleize(s):
    s = s.strip('()').split(',')
    return tuple(int(entry) for entry in s)

pixels = [tupleize(pixel) for pixel in pixels]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It's a good approach also.